# kubectl apply -k [dir] gives error must be a directory to be a root

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my folder, I have a **deployment.yaml** file and a **kustomization.yaml**
Inside the **kustomization.yaml**:

```
bases:
- ../base
- deployment.yaml
```

When I run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`, it runs successfully
but when running `kubectl apply -k [folder name]` then it gives the error message: `error: couldn't make loader for deployment.yaml: got file 'deployment.yaml', but '/[absolute path of the folder]/deployment_azure.yaml' must be a directory to be a root`

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the folder is a symlink to another folder or nfs share
It should be hard local directory to be able to apply yaml files in it from kubectl